# Suppress home directory check while SSHing to remote host for user without home directory

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to suppress the home directory check while we do the ssh to remote host.

I tried to set the `StrictMode=no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` on both ssh client and server as found in some solutions but it did not work in my case.

Reason I need this is because the user I’m using for SSH, doesn’t have home directory created on the remote server, this is by design for some security reasons.

And when I do the SSH, it gives me warning that the home directory not available.

And this warning is causing some of my automated functionality to fail.

```
[root@my-host /]# ssh kuser@my-remote-host uname -a

Could not chdir to home directory /home/kuser: No such file or directory
Linux my-remote-host 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 18 20:25:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there any way to suppress this message?

Comment: You say you are doing this for security reasons, but honestly this seems like overkill. There is no real reason for a user to not have a home directory; I cannot imagine the security value in this kind of architecture.

Comment: IMHO, @Giacomo1968 couldn't be more correct.  Not having a home directory was invented for processes and services/daemons, not additional security.

Comment: Try `ssh kuser@my-remote-host 'cd /; uname -a'`

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo1968 for a response. The reason I need this is because this is what implemented at one of our customer and I need a way to handle that error. I did a workaround for now to create a error and output streams and ignore the error stream.